# Symfony 2 using Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I am using Symfony 2 with Postgresql.

I use schemas and put in my entities this code:

```
/**
 * NameTable
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="schema.NameTable")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

If I do the command

> php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

It`s works but I must to generate the schema "schema" manually.The command only generates the table not the schema.

Are there another way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if u want to change the default schema you can use the following annotation, otherwise Symfony just take the public schema as default.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

/**
 * @Table(schema="some_schema")
 */
class Entity 
{
    // ...
}
```